# How to use /tools/randomTrips.py on ubuntu

Tags: sumo, flow-project

My os system is 18.04. The sumo version is 1.2.0
I want to use the tool - randomTrip.
I input the command like that:

```
python ~/sumo/tools/randomTrips.py  -n xxx.net.xml -r xxx.rou.xml -e 50 -l
```

But the error log is that:

> `File "/home/dnl/sumo/tools/randomTrips.py", line 506, in <module>
>           if not main(get_options()):
>         File "/home/dnl/sumo/tools/randomTrips.py", line 485, in main
>           subprocess.call(args)
>         File "/home/dnl/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 247, in call
>           with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
>         File "/home/dnl/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
>           restore_signals, start_new_session)
>         File "/home/dnl/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1289, in _execute_child
>           raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
>       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'duarouterD'`

So, how to deal with it? I can run it on Windows OS, but cannot on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

this seems like a SUMO issue rather than a Flow issue? I'd post this on their github page.

Comment: yeah, the question tags are sumo & flow-project.